# Deregister admin editor reset styles with the handle of wp-reset-editor-styles

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to remove **wp-reset-editor-styles** because it inserts CSS properties like like **revert**, which goes against what I'm trying to accomplish (example below).

```
.editor-styles-wrapper p {
  font-size: revert;
  line-height: revert;
  margin: revert;
}
```

Here's what I've attempted.

```
function remove_editor_resets() {
  wp_deregister_style('wp-reset-editor-styles');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_editor_resets');
```

It successfully removes the resets, but ends up breaking another style called **wp-block-directory**. Here's what the relevant section of the **load-styles.php** URL looks like.

**BEFORE:** wp-block-directory

**AFTER:** wp-bloc&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=k-directory

I've attempted `define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );` but that does nothing.

I believe the issue has something to do with the way dependencies are setup in **/wp-includes/script-loader.php**.

Comment: You might try to register your own replacement after deregistering `wp_register_style( 'wp-reset-editor-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom-wp-reset-editor-styles.css', false, '1.0.0' );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. Try `enqueue_block_editor_assets` instead of `admin_menu`. Note that this will also remove some core styles needed by the editor.

This seems to be a problem that a lot of people are having. Until WP releases an update around this, I think this is the best you can do (*there may be additional styles needed*):

```
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', function () {
    // Removes editor styles
    wp_deregister_style('wp-reset-editor-styles');
    // Add back key styles, there may be more
    // change the path as needed
    wp_enqueue_style('wp-block-editor-styles', '../../../wp/wp-includes/css/dist/block-editor/style.css', false);
    wp_enqueue_style('wp-edit-post-styles', '../../../wp/wp-includes/css/dist/edit-post/style.css', false);
}, 102);
```

**Note:** Tested on WP v5.8.3

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. All the "revert" porperties simply broke up my CSS on gutenberg preview.
Here is the solution that I finally implemented on my website.

- create an add_action on "enqueue_block_editor_assets".
- Deregister "wp-reset-editor-styles"
- Register a new stylesheet (with your custom CSS) and use as handle "wp-reset-editor-styles". You need to do this because wp-edit-blocks needs it as dependency.

So now I have the following code :

```
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'my_enqueue_block_editor_assets', 102);
function my_enqueue_block_editor_assets () {
    wp_deregister_style('wp-reset-editor-styles');
    wp_register_style( 'wp-reset-editor-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/stylesheets/my-custom-stylesheet.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
}
```

Works perfectly on WP v5.9.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a version of the code shown above from Blass industries, except that if you want your code to be more portable (for example, for a plugin), use includes_url() rather than specifying the full path. For my RSVPMaker plugin, I also fetch styling rules that can be set dynamically by the user and write them to be a file that can be loaded using this method.

```
function rsvpmailer_gutenberg_editor_css()
{
global $post;
if('rsvpemail' != $post->post_type)
    return;
wp_deregister_style('wp-reset-editor-styles');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-block-editor-styles', includes_url('css/dist/block-editor/style.css'));
wp_enqueue_style('wp-edit-post-styles', includes_url('css/dist/edit-post/style.css'));
  $css = rsvpmaker_get_style_substitutions_file();
  $version = time();
  wp_enqueue_style('rsvpmailer-editor-css', $css, [], get_rsvpversion());
}
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'rsvpmailer_gutenberg_editor_css',999);
```